# Turning ModelingToolkit.Constant into eg. a Complex{Float64}?

Tags: julia, symbolic-math

I would like to switch from using ForwardDiff to ModelingToolkit to calculate a Jacobian, as this would have many advantages for me. 
Is it possible to convert a **ModelingToolkit.constant** into e.g. a **complex{Float64}**?
I need to use the actual value of the constant in another function.
More specifically, I am looking for a method that does the following:
`ModelingToolkit.constant(42.0 - 42.0im) -> 42.0 - 42.0im`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelingToolkit.Constant(1.0+1.0im).value == 1.0+1.0im`